# How do you check if a string has something from the list and print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to make a program that takes one word from the user and checks from a list of vowels and prints the vowels that are found in that word and how many were found. This is what I have so far, it's super incorrect but I tried something.

```
print("This program will count the total number of vowels in the word you enter.")

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
userWord = input("Please enter a single word: ")
if vowels in userWord:
    print(vowels)
    vowelCount = 0
    
    vowelCount = vowelCount + 1
    
    print("There are " + vowelCount + " total vowels in " + userWord)
```

Comment: You can't check the whole vowel list at once like that. You have to iterate over it and check each one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can do if you are starting out with Python is to iterate over every letter in the input word.

In each iteration you then check if the letter is in the vowel list like so:

```python
print("This program will count the total number of vowels in the word you enter.")

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
userWord = input("Please enter a single word: ")
vowelCount = 0
foundVowels = []

for letter in userWord:
    if letter in vowels:
        foundVowels.append(letter)
        vowelCount += 1
print("There are " + str(vowelCount) + " total vowels in " + userWord + ": " + str(foundVowels))
```

Comment: how would I print the vowels that are found in the word?

Comment: You can create an empty list that grabs each vowel that is found, I updated my code to include this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sum()` function to count the number of vowels in the word. The generator expression produces `True` for each vowel that is found at least once, and `True` counts as `1` to `sum()`.

```
vowelCount = sum(vowel in userWord for vowel in vowels)
print(f"There are {vowelCount} total vowels in {userWord}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u']
count=0
ls=[]
wordfromUser=input("Enter a word: ")
for i in wordfromUser:
  if i in vowels:
    count+=1
    ls.append(i)
print("There are " + str(count) + " total vowels in " + wordfromUser)
```